# Linear bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I'm a bit stuck on a exercise, here it is.
Let $X = C[0,1]$ be the space of continous functions on $[0,1]$ with real values.

X is a normed space with respect to the $L²$  norm: $(\int_{0}^{1} |f(t)| dt)^\frac{1}{2}$.

Let T be a linear operator defined on X, such that:

$ For f \in X, $ $$Tf = \int _{0}^{1} x²f(x) dx$$

The first question is to show that T is bounded for all $f$ in $X$, which I've completed thanks to Cauchy Schwarz and this is fine because $x² \in X$ like $f(x)$, (hence $\in L²$), and therefore I've found:

$$||T|| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$$

Then we're asked to compute (or derivate ?) the operator norm of $T$, that is to show that $||T|| = \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$.

I can't find any form of $f$ in $X$ such that $||f||_{2} = 1 $, and  I end up having $||T|| \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$

Can anyone give me a clue on how to prove this ?

Comment: Can you make equality hold in your Cauchy-schwarz inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $g(x) = \sqrt{5}x^2$ has the desired properties: $\vert\vert g \vert\vert = 1$ and $Tg = 1/\sqrt{5}$.

How did I find $g$? The Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality is an equality, if and only if the two functions you're estimating are linearly dependent. Thus it makes sense to consider functions $ax^2$.

Comment: Thank you ! I totally understand now, I just forgot the linearly dependent case. Thanks again !